Yehoshua: a leader or a shepherd?
In Bamidbar 27:16, we read that Moshe pleads to G-d that He will set a leader over the Jewish People that will continue to lead them:

Let the L-rd, the G-d of the spirits of all flesh, set a man over the congregation

The reason the Torah gives us is so that B'nei Yisroel will have a shepherd that leads "the flock" (v. 17):

who may go out before them, and who may go in before them, and who may lead them out, and may bring them in; that the congregation of the L-rd be not as sheep that have no shepherd.

In Chabad-Chassidus, the concept that Moshe Rabbeinu is the faithful shepherd of the Jewish people, is discussed in many maamorim from different Rebbeim. The Rebbe talks about this in Maamar VeAtat Tetzaveh, 5741. He also quotes the Rebbe Raayatz in the Mamaar "VeKibeil HaYehudim". It is explained that:
a) a faithful shepherd of the Jewish people means that he faithfully tends to the needs of the Jewish people
b) a shepherd of faith means that he sustains and nurtures the faith of the Jewish people.
Both terms apply to the description of Moshe Rabbeinu as the "raaya mehemna".
However, I found something interesting.
The Chida, in his Pnei David, writes that the meaning of the posuk "Let the L-rd, the G-d of the spirits of all flesh, set a man over the congregation" is that:

It is possible that the manner of the leader is that he goes ahead of the people, whereas the manner of a shepherd is that he follows the flock. Our Sages, may their memory be blessed, have also said this.

The Chida goes on to quote different meforshim that say that our posuk, al-pi-peshat, refers to when the people are going out to war. Then they need a leader.
Based on the idea that a leader goes "ahead of the people", whereas a shepherd "follows his flock". How can we interpret Moshe's plea to G-d that the Jewish people? It would seem that they need someone like Moshe, like tending his flock, and not leading people in case of war.
They needed someone who nurtures the faith, and not prepare them for war. Right? Any ideas on this?

why can moshe be asking for both, a leader and a shepherd? yehoshua needed to lead the wars in israel and also needed to be shepherd and pass the torch of torah

@Mordechai but the emphasis lies on being a leader, not a person that nurtures faith.

I would suggest since Yehoshua may not have been a natural leader but a follower. Yehoshua was like the moon https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Batra.75a.16 that only reflects light but does not give off it's own

I think you are looking at this too rigidly. These are not descriptions of the physical location of a leader but a manner of leading by example. As such they are not in contradiction to each other.
